# How to use Xamarin DataTemplateSelector with DataTemplates organized in folders?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary, datatemplateselector

I'm trying to implement something like this MS Docs sample, with the DataTemplates as separate files:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

My folder structure...

```
Project
 |
 └─ Views\
     |  MyView.xaml
     |
     └───DataTemplates\
           DT1.xaml (no .cs)
           DT2.xaml (no .cs)
           DTSelector.cs
```

From MyView.xaml...

```
<ContentPage ...             
    xmlns:datatemplates="clr-namespace: Project.Views.DataTemplates"/>
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>       
            <datatemplates:DT1/> 
            <datatemplates:DT2/>
            <!-- This is the x:Key name, right? -->
            <!-- Intellisense can't find these  -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <datatemplates:DTSelector x:Key="dTSelector"        
            DT1= "{StaticResource dT1}"
            DT2= "{StaticResource dT2}"/> 

    </ResourceDictionary>
```

From a DataTemplate...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">    
    <!-- x:Class has been removed -->
    <DataTemplate x:Name="DT1" x:Key="dT1">
        <Grid, etc...
```

DataTemplateSelector...

```
public class DTSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{    
    public DataTemplate DT1{ get; set; }
    public DataTemplate DT2{ get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {    
        switch (App.CurrentUser.SomeEnum)
        {
            case SomeEnum.Pref1:
                 return DT1;
                 break;
            case SomeEnum.Pref2:
                return DT2;
                break;
            default:
                return DT1;
        }
    }
}
```

I have wrestled the code into the App level and got it to compile, but then DTSelector's always returns a null object, and it throws an exception.  I'd prefer it at the page level, anyhow.  It seems like there should be a... ResourceDictionary Source="DT1.xaml" x:Key="DT1" but that's not valid.

I assume MyView can't find the templates via xmlns because Intellisense only sees cs files... but I get a green squiggle and compilation error XLS0414: "The type 'datatemplates:DT1' not found..."

GitRepo here, for your pleasure:
https://github.com/BullCityCabinets/DataTemplateSelectorExample201014

Thanks for any help!

Comment: it doesn't matter if intellisense is able to see it or not , run the project and check

Comment: @Shubham Tyagi  "... and compilation error XLS0414: 'The type 'datatemplates:DT1' not found..."

Comment: can you make a git repo and share that

Comment: Added above: https://github.com/BullCityCabinets/DataTemplateSelectorExample201014

Answer (score 0):

I found if you put the `DT1.xaml` and `MyView.xaml` in the same folder. You can reference the resource dictionary by :

```
<ContentPage.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary Source="DT1.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DT2.xaml" />

    <datatemplates:DTSelector x:Key="dTSelector"        
            DT1ref = "{StaticResource DT1key}"
            DT2ref = "{StaticResource DT2key}"/>

</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And the folder:

[image]

Refer: [merge-local-resource-dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#merge-local-resource-dictionaries)

Comment: Without a selector, folders work like,  <ResourceDictionary Source="DataTemplates\DT1.xaml" />, but I didin't think the selector found them.  Let me see if I'd just fat-fingered something after adding the selector... I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like they all have to be in the same folder, but reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datatemplateselector?view=xamarin-forms makes it sound like the DataTemplateSelector could go find the file... "this.templateOne = new DataTemplate (typeof (ViewA));" I haven't had time to try it out yet, though.  Otherwise, I guess the answer is "Naming Convention, Naming Convention, Naming Convention", right?

Comment: You should find what is `ViewA` there, when you write a DT1.xaml, it is only a ResourceDictionary.